# how to print javascript text into a form using a button

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm attempting to combine my limited knowledge of HTML and JavaScript for practice and can't seem to get past this snag. I'm trying to make it so when I click the button the random cards appear in the form above the button. Is there may be a better way to do this?

```js
function randomCards() {
  const cards = ['diamond', 'spade', 'heart', 'club'];
  let currentCard = ''
  while (currentCard != 'spade') {
    currentCard = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  Cards:<br>
  <input type='text' name="Card Slot">
</form>
<button onclick='randomCards()'>Get Cards</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `value` received to the `input`. Use `document.querySelector` to get the `input` element and using `.value`, set the value of the input

```js
function randomCards() {
  document.querySelector('#a').value = "";
  const cards = ['dimond', 'spade', 'heart', 'club'];
  let currentCard = ''
  while (currentCard != 'spade') {
    currentCard = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
    document.querySelector('#a').value += currentCard +
      " "
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  Cards:<br>
  <input type='text' name="Card Slot" id="a">
</form>
<button onclick='randomCards()'>Get Cards</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer with minimal changes to your HTML structure:

```html
<form>
  Cards:<br>
  <input type='text' name="Card Slot">
</form>
<button onclick='randomCards()'>Get Cards</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function randomCards() {
    document.getElementsByName("Card Slot")[0].value = '';
    const cards = ['dimond', 'spade', 'heart', 'club'];
    let currentCard = ''
    while (currentCard != 'spade') {
      currentCard = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
      document.getElementsByName("Card Slot")[0].value += currentCard + ' ';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function randomCards() {
    const cards = ['dimond', 'spade', 'heart', 'club'];
    let currentCard = ''
    while(currentCard != 'spade') {
        currentCard = cards [Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];
    }
    console.log(currentCard);
    $('#test3').val(currentCard);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
  Cards:<br>
  <input type='text' id="test3" name="Card Slot">
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<button onclick= 'randomCards()'>Get Cards</button>
</body>
</html>
```

here `while(currentCard != 'spade') {
            currentCard = cards [Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];
        }`

will always gives spade, if you want random you can remove while and put `currentCard = cards [Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];`